# docker build network error when trying to pip install

Tags: django, docker, build

I am building my first docker install as part of learning  django.  I have my docker install working.  docker info is ok.  and hello-world says successfull.  But when I run the Dockerfile suggested by the turorial in my Django 3.0 Pro Book by Will Vincent. I get  what look like a network dns error.

################
Error:

```
    Step 6/7 : RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system
 ---> Running in 585e5020f53a
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f339144df10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/pipenv/
   
 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f3391f05a90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/pipenv/
   
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f3391f05e90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/pipenv/
    
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f3391f05ad0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/pipenv/
    
    WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f33915ddd90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/pipenv/
    
    ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pipenv (from versions: none)
    
    ERROR: No matching distribution found for pipenv
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

####################

Dockerfile  try to build:

## Pull base image

```
FROM python:3.7

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set work directory
WORKDIR /code

# Install dependencies
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system

# Copy project
COPY . /code/
```

It is failing on the RUN pip install....   line.

I have added dns nameserver entries directly into my /etc/resolver.conf file as other have suggested in my search here.   not worked.

I assume there is some issue within Docker trying to run pip in the container? This is my first Docker install so exhausted search for answer.

On OS version Centos8

Thanks
bill sanderson

Comment: `systemctl restart docker` fixed the issue for me (reconfiguring docker network).

Answer (score 9):

Ok, we can try a couple of things. First thing I would do:

- In the Dockerfile add this(with google's dns):

`RUN echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf && pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system`

It is important to do in the same RUN command.

- Another option is:

`docker build --network=host -t yourimage:yourversion .`

Comment: I had set my resolver to google  8.8.8.8...  which did not work.  

I was able to run  docker building --network=host      which fix my build error.

problem now is when i do   docker-compose up.   the  same network error return as I have with docker buld.... when it tries to rebuild.     i do not wee a network option on docker-compose...   

thanks

Comment: Take a look at this: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: But if you have so many troubles with your network config, maybe you should have to check your BIP docker setting in /etc/docker/daemon.json (put something like this to avoid networking conflicts):

```"bip" : "10.10.0.1/24"```

Another thing you can check is ```docker network ls``` and look for something weird, like another network in conflict.

Comment: I dumped centos8 and installed ubuntu 20.04 LTS and went thru same docker setup. all is working now .... nothing special needed beyond same docker install instructions. thanks -- bill s. –

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue last night - and this morning.  Even after rebooting and trying to stop/start the service.  This is on my Windows 10.

I did notice running a `docker info` output the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: open \\.\pipe\docker_engine_linux: The system cannot find the file specified
```

As detailed here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74098179/405022

Having ran `wsl --shutdown` and being prompted to restart docker desktop, I then proceeded to try my docker build.

```
docker build -f ./sources/service1/deploy/dev.dockerfile ./sources/service1 -t acme-app.service1-py:latest --no-cache --progress=plain
```

Coincidence?  It worked for me in the end.