# Docker endpoint for "default" not found

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

I did clone a project and in the first step when I tried to start the container, I did run windows CMD in my project root and I type this command:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

and this message is shown to me:

> docker endpoint for "default" not found.

I'll be more than happy if somebody helps me. When I write this command for the first time I had an internet problem it got paused, in second time started to download something then this message printed.

I tried to delete my old Containers, also I try with my VPN on and off, and restart docker in PowerShell.

Comment: your problem seem to be the same as this one https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/9956 , take a look at the answers in this

Answer (score 177, accepted):

For Windows Users

1. Delete `.docker` directory. Which exists on PATH `C:\Users\your-username\.docker`
2. Restart docker.

Comment: i did it and worked, then i witched to Linux

Comment: good it works for me

Comment: Thank you. Fixed the error after updating from 4.15 to 4.16

Comment: why the hell does that work? well, it does.

Comment: for me it was enough just to delete the `meta.json` file %USER_PROFILE%\.docker\contexts\meta\{some ver random characters }\meta.json

Comment: Miraculously it worked for me as well.

Comment: worked without restart

Comment: Deleting whole directory without explonation is not correct answer. See reply by @rafael-xavier

Comment: Agreed, but in this scenario, it won't cause any harm. As @rafael-xavier has also written. If it would have impacted anything I would've added the disclaimer. Hope it helps you !

Comment: @RobertNiestroj Confirmed. This seems to be sufficient in my case as well.

Comment: Restart didn't work. Needed to quit Docker Desktop and start it again.

Answer (score 58):

This comment helped me better then nuking the whole directory:

https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/9956#issuecomment-1294483086

(check an empty meta.json in ~/.docker/contexts/meta/(somelong hash)/meta.json, delete it)

Answer (score 22):

Please follow these steps bellow:

1. Stop Docker Desktop and all containers.
2. Go to path:

`~/.docker/contexts/meta/(some sha256)/meta.json`

Using Windows it should be on:

`C:\Users\YOUR_USER\.docker\contexts\meta\(some sha256)\meta.json`

This meta.json file should be just full of NULLs or empty.

3. Delete this hashed path with this meta.json file inside of it.
4. Restart Docker

Done.

---

Notes:

- Please backup before deleting.
- Don't be afraid to lost data because this way we should remove ONLY this NULL/Empty file (and folder). Just be aware to not delete any important files.

Answer (score 4):

Try to delete ".docker" folder.
This helped in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Try to delete ".docker" folder. This helped in my case.

run- ".docker"- delete the folder

Answer (score 2):

1. Open folder `C:\Users\<YOUR-USER-NAME>\`
2. Rename `.docker` directory. with `.docker_temp`
3. Restart `docker`
4. Run command `docker-compose up --build`

Its works!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get this working following all the suggestions. In the end I edited the empty meta.json file under C:\Users\USERNAME\.docker\contexts\meta\GUID\meta.json, and just pasted the following from a previously working file:

```
{"Name":"temp","Metadata":{"StackOrchestrator":"swarm"},"Endpoints":{"docker":{"Host":"unix:///var/run/docker.sock","SkipTLSVerify":false}}}
```

Then it started working again!

Answer (score 0):

In linux environmnmet, you can do

```py
rm -rf ~/.docker/contexts/meta/
```